# Is there a variable to see if a website has been deployed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

As the title says really - is there a built in c# (or MVC) variable, ie something in httpcontext or something like that, that can tell me if the site has been deployed to the live server (or if it is running locally) or do I need to put something into the web.config?

Also does

```
#if DEBUG

#endif
```

Only fire locally or can a deployed site also run in debug mode?

Comment: Yes, a deployed site can also run in debug mode; actually, it is possible for your views and regular code to **disagree** on whether it is in debug mode, since views are compiled separately to the regular code. Do not use `#if DEBUG` to test this.

Comment: `#if DEBUG` is a *compiler condition*, it's not location aware. If you build your site with this condition then this code will run (regardless of where the site is hosted). It's generally recommended that you have a `RELEASE` compiler condition which does things like code optimizations etc. for your production site and compile using that instead.

Comment: thanks guys, think I'll just shove something in the web.config then

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built-in that you can use. You need to give your application that capability yourself.

If you know the IP address or domain name of the "live" web server, you can use `Request.ServerVariables["LOCAL_ADDR"]` or the `Request.Url.Host` property respectively to determine whether or not it has been deployed.

```
public bool IsDeployed()
{
    return Request.ServerVariables["LOCAL_ADDR"] == "123.123.123.123";
    // or for domain name
    return Request.Url.Host == "mydomain.com";
}
```